# Maintain native size on loaded swf into as3 movie

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Anyone know how to maintain the original stage size of a externally loaded swf in as3 FP10??

I can't find any documentation on it and don't want to mask it.

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That's not the way it's designed to work. You can set the loader's width and height after load, but you'll have to mask it if you have things hanging off the stage in the loaded SWF.

Answer (score 1):

After the loader completed loading, it has the original width and height of your external swf.

By calling `addChild(loader);` you place the swf in your DisplayObject.

Comment: Yeah, so is there a way of adding the swf to the display and without it picking up your loader swfs Display properties?